# Exact same python code does not work on different computers

Tags: python, pygame

The exact same code from my friend's windows computer does not work with my macbook and vice versa. We both get the same error, "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" and the problem starts when we start importing png files. Otherwise normal code without needing the file directory works fine.

This was our tile module

```
import pygame
from support import import_folder


class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size, size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))


def update(self, shift):
    self.rect.x += shift


class StaticTile(Tile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y, surface):
        super().__init__(size, x, y)
        self.image = surface

class AnimatedTile(Tile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y, path):
        super().__init__(size, x, y)
        self.frames = import_folder(path)
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.image = self.frames[self.frame_index]

    def animate(self):
        self.frame_index += 0.15
        if self.frame_index >= len(self.frames):
            self.frame_index = 0
        self.image = self.frames[int(self.frame_index)]

    def update(self, shift):
        self.animate()
        self.rect.x += shift
```

This was our enemy module

```
import pygame
from tiles import AnimatedTile
from random import randint


class Enemy(AnimatedTile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y):
        super().__init__(size, x, y, '../graphics/0/enemy/slay/1.png')
        self.rect.y += size - self.image.get_size()[1]
        self.speed = randint(3, 5)

    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed

    def reverse_image(self):
        if self.speed > 0:
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)

    def reverse(self):
        self.speed *= -1

    def update(self, shift):
        self.rect.x += shift
        self.animate()
        self.move()
        self.reverse_image()
```

This is our first time coding a game so some help will really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons behind it, for example different python versions. Different library versions, different operational systems. If you are going to share your code and build a project, i recommed using either  a docker or vcs with venvs

Answer (score -1):

Windows and Mac(unix type os's) separate folders in path using opposite slashes
'/' for unix and '\' for Windows

you will need to detect os and format '../graphics/0/enemy/slay/1.png' accordingly

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
   # Windows
else:
   # non Windows
```